# ts-jest does not recognize es6 imports

Tags: typescript, babeljs, jestjs, es6-modules

I'm adding typescript support to a react codebase, and while the app is working ok, jest tests are failing all over the place, apparently not recognizing something about es6 syntax.

We're using [ts-jest](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#tsconfig) for this. Below is the error message I'm getting, right off the bat when trying to process jest's tests setup file.

```
 FAIL  src/data/reducers/reducers.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/ernesto/code/app/react/setupTests.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import './polyfills';
                                                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected string

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

It fails to recognize a simple `import './polyfills'`, saying that the quoted string is unexpected.

These are my settings:

jest config in package.json

```
"jest": {
  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>/app/react/setupTests.js",
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(jsx?|tsx?)$",
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "ts",
    "tsx",
    "js",
    "jsx",
    "json",
    "node"
  ]
},
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true
  },
  "exclude": ["app/assets","node_modules", "vendor", "public"],
  "compileOnSave": false
}
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "env",
      {
        "modules": false,
        "targets": {
          "browsers": "> 1%",
          "uglify": true
        },
        "useBuiltIns": true
      }
    ],
    "react",
    "es2015"
  ],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    [
      "transform-class-properties",
      {
        "spec": true
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

In case it is relevant, this is a React codebase being used inside a rails app, and we're using [rails/webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/releases) to that end. We followed [their instructions to add TypeScript support to it](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/master/docs/typescript.md), and it worked like a charm, except for this jest part, which they do not cover.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I eventually found out what the problem was. It turns out it was there in ts-jest's README all the time.

There's a section in the README titled [Using ES2015+ features in Javascript files](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#using-es2015-features-in-javascript-files). In these cases, you need to instruct jest to use `babel-jest` as a transform for .js files.

```
"jest": {
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest", // Adding this line solved the issue
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  // ...
},
```

Comment: Not working in tsx with "import React from 'react'", only works with astersisk as.

Comment: This is the link to the documentation where the configuration is explained: [link](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/guides/esm-support). What @Ernesto provided is the Github repo.

Answer (score 3):

The key for me was realizing the **tests should be converted to typescript too**, or, add allowJs to your tsconfig.json

I was not able to find a config that worked with keeping js tests, but converting the tests to ts fixes this error e.g.

`mv tests/stuff.test.js tests/stuff.test.ts`

The benefit of ts-jest in general is the ability to have ts tests so it is a good thing to go with anyways

Comment: note also that you can add `//@ts-nocheck` at the top of the file if you want to rename your test to ts but not do typechecking on it

Comment: also note: instead of renaming everything to .ts, using allowJs:true and adding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58370492/ts-jest-fails-to-run-a-tsx-test-file-because-of-import-from-a-modules-js-file this to the jest.config.js also may be an option 
```"transform": {
    "^.+\\.(ts|js)x?$": "ts-jest"
  },```

Answer (score 1):

As [the documentation you found](https://github.com/kulshekhar/ts-jest#tsconfig) says, ts-jest requires CommonJS modules, so since your main `tsconfig.json` sets `"module": "es6"`, you'll need to create a separate `tsconfig.json` file for ts-jest that extends your main `tsconfig.json` and sets `"module": "commonjs"`.

Comment: I did see that, and tried it without luck. I just tried it again, and I still get the same error. To be clear, I added a `tsconfig.jest.json` to the root of my project, and added a section in the jest config with the settings for global/ts-jest/tsConfigFile set to this new tsconfig file. This new config file in turn extends the base tsconfig, specifying only the new setting for modules to be commonjs.

Comment: Moreover, if I change my default tsconfig to say "commonjs", I still get the same error. I'm fearing that this setting then means that my actual jest source files must use the commonjs notation instead of es6's for imports? If that's so, I'll have to change my entire tests sources to switch from `import` to `require` :(

Comment: Anyway, thanks. At least you've set me in the right direction. It must have something to do with that, so I'll double-check everything in case I'm still doing something wrong.

Comment: Ah.  If you have _JavaScript_ source files that use `import`, you probably need to either manually change them to `require` or register a transformer of some kind in your jest configuration that can do that conversion for you internally.  Maybe this would just be a custom Babel configuration for jest?  I've never used jest; I'm just working from a general understanding of JavaScript build processes.

Answer (score -5):

> #### If you are using **create-react-app**  , try this :

Even though create-react-app comes pre-configured, we still had to add in custom configuration since our app wasn't initially built with cra. I installed some new dev dependencies:

```
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-jest": "^22.4.1",
"babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.1",
```

And also updated the `.babelrc` (create this file if it doesn't exist ) :

```
{
"presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react"
      ]
}
```

And now both jest and npm test both work as they should.