# How can I run Jest tests with an imported library that is made available in es2015 modules? (Jest encountered unexpected token error)

Tags: typescript

I have two npm packages. I provide direct links to the repos, but also the relevant code snippets and descriptions below.

**Here is the summary of the question and what is detailed further below**

- Project 1 uses TypeScript option `"module": "es2015"` to compile it's code
- Project 2 has project 1 as a dependency. This project has one test file, which tests an object which makes a call to code from the imported project 1.
- Jest gives an error when we run this project 2 test. The error basically says that there is an error in the code of the imported library.
- When in project 1 I change the TypeScript option to something else, or omit it, the compiled code is of course not `es2015`, but the project 2 test works.
- How can I make it so that the Jest test works with the `es2015` option in the imported library?

**Here are the details**

[Here](https://github.com/evian-pring/TypedNpmModule) is a very simple TypeScript npm module, let's call it project 1. It has one `index.ts` file that exports an object with one method in it. I executed `yarn tsc` to generate an `index.js` file in a `./lib` folder, with an auto-generated declaration file `index.d.ts`. I've gitignored the `src/index.ts`, so the repo only shows the `lib` folder that would be available were this repo to be published as an npm module in the npm registry.

These are the relevant files:

```
// tsconfig.js
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "sourceMap": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "declaration": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "lib"]
}
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "TypedNpmModule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "tsc": "tsc"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  }
}
```

```
// src/index.ts
export const myObject = {
  method1: function(str: string) {
    return str;
  }
};
```

The TypeScript generated `.js` file is

```
export var myObject = {
  method1: function(str) {
    return str;
  },
};
```

[Here](https://github.com/evian-pring/jest1) is a very simple TypeScript npm module, let's call it project 2, that imports project 1. It has an `index.ts` exports an `actions` object that has a method that just calls the method that we get from the object exported in project 1:

```
// src/index.ts
import { myObject } from 'TypedNpmModule';

export const actions = {
  meth1: myObject.method1('hello'),
};
```

This project uses `Jest` to test calling this `actions` object:

```
// src/__tests__/index.test.js
import { actions } from '../index';

test('actions', () => {
  const result = actions.meth1('hello');
  expect(result).toMatchSnapshot();
});
```

```
// package.json
{
  "name": "Jest1",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.12",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "prettier": "^1.17.0",
    "ts-jest": "^24.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.4.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "TypedNpmModule": "evian-pring/TypedNpmModule#master"
  },
  "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
    }
  }
}
```

**This is where the problem is**

When I run the Jest tests, using `npx jest`, I get an error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that Jest by default ignores all files in `node_modules`. Therefore, no transformations are applied to any external libraries. I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173815/ts-jest-does-not-recognize-es6-imports) other thread that `ts-jest` requires files to use `commonjs`, and since `project1`'s files are using ES6 native modules, we get an error.

Solution:

- In `project 2`, tell Jest to not ignore `project1` package. This is done in the Jest config, under key `transformIgnorePatterns`. Read more about that [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transformignorepatterns-array-string)
- In `project 2`, install babel correctly: besides `babel-jest` we also need `@babel/core` and `@babel/preset-core`. `yarn add --dev @babel/core @babel/preset/core babel-jest`
- I think this is also a requirement since Babel 7: use a `babel.config.js` file not a `.babelrc` file. [Here](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6053#issuecomment-383632515) is why. This is what the one for `project2` looks like

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);

  const presets = ["@babel/env"];

  return {
    presets
  };
};
```

See also the repos linked in the question for the working code.